# I need to set up routing to get value from mysql with node and express. I can do with Query paramas but I cannot do it with Query Strings

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express, backend

```
    incRouter.route('/incidents/:Inc_num',)
      .get((req, res) => {
       MySQL.query("select INCIDENT_NUM, IMPACTED_APPS, INC_DATE, IMPACT_HOURS_TYPE, INCIDENT_TYPE, INC_DURATION, CORE_IMPACT_MINS, INC_MONTH from table WHERE INCIDENT_NUM = ?", [req.query.Inc_num],
          (err, result, rows) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(`Query Error ${err}`);
              connection.end();

        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
          console.log(result);
          res.status(200).json(result);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hey, could you please add full details of what you're trying to achieve, what you've already tried, what errors you're getting, and anything else that's relevant? It's really hard to figure out what the problem is when we only get the title and a short code snippet. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a great guide, if you follow that you're more likely to get high quality answers to your questions :)

Comment: I'm trying to make the routes respond with the value when using a query string but It returns me the same incident route (/Incidents).